# Is $Z[i]/(1+3i)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+3i)$ a field? I know it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,1+3x)$, but have no idea how to proceed from there on.

Thanks for your answer in advance!

Comment: Hint:  $1+3i = (1+i)(2+i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(1+i)(2+i) = 2+i+2i-1=1+3i$. Thus the image of $(1+i)$ in $Z[i](1+3i)$ is a divisor of zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't quite understand... So this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i,2+i)$?

Comment: A field don't have divisor of zero, since every non zero element in a field is invertible

Comment: Then why don't we directly say that the image of $(1+3i)$ in the quotient ring is a divisor of zero?

Comment: because it is zero

Comment: Every non-zero ring has a zero-divisor: $0$. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor#Zero_as_a_zero_divisor

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shown that the ring is isomorphic to $Z[x]/(x^2+1,1+3x)$, $x^2+1-(1+3x)=x^2-3x=x(x-3)$. Thus the image of $x$ in $Z[x]/(x^2+1,1+3x)$ is a divisor of zero.

Comment: So this quotient ring transformation preserves zero divisors?

Comment: It is not field because non zero elements in a field are invertible.

Comment: Then why is $1+i$ not invertible? It is a zero divisor but can't it have an inverse then?

Comment: @rufflerocks zero divisors cannot have an inverse. You should be able to prove this. Give it a shot.